# Generate songs based off of inputted songs using Tensorflow's Magenta in Node.js

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, magenta

I'm wondering if it's possible to input a bunch of songs into Magenta and get an output that mimics those songs using AI (something that I feel like Magenta should be able to do).

For example, I could input a bunch of Beatles songs and get a song that sounds something like they would play.

Is this possible? Would it generate the lyrics and the song title?